# C++ unsafe cast workaround

Tags: c++, virtual

In a complex codebase, I have an array of non-virtual base class pointer (the base class has no virtual methods)

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TBase
{
    public:
        TBase(int i = 0) : m_iData(i) {}
        ~TBase(void) {}

        void Print(void) {std::cout << "Data = " << m_iData << std::endl;}

    protected:
        int     m_iData;
};

class TStaticDerived : public TBase
{
    public:
        TStaticDerived(void) : TBase(1) {}
        ~TStaticDerived(void)  {}
};

class TVirtualDerived : public TBase
{
    public:
        TVirtualDerived(void) : TBase(2) {}
        virtual ~TVirtualDerived(void) {} //will force the creation of a VTABLE
};

void PrintType(TBase *pBase)
{
    pBase->Print();
}

void PrintType(void** pArray, size_t iSize)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        TBase *pBase = (TBase*) pArray[i];
        pBase->Print();
    }
}


int main()
{
    TBase b(0);
    TStaticDerived sd;
    TVirtualDerived vd;

    PrintType(&b);
    PrintType(&sd);
    PrintType(&vd); //OK

    void* vArray[3];
    vArray[0] = &b;
    vArray[1] = &sd;
    vArray[2] = &vd; //VTABLE not taken into account -> pointer not OK
    PrintType(vArray, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is (compiled with Mingw-w64 GCC 4.9.2 on Win64):

```
Data = 0
Data = 1
Data = 2
Data = 0
Data = 1
Data = 4771632
```

The reason of the failure is that each instance of TVirtualDerived has a pointer to the virtual table, which TBase has not. So up-casting to TBase without previous type information (from void* to TBase*) is not safe.

The thing is that I cannot avoid casting to void* in the first place.
Adding a virtual method (destructor for example) on the base class works, but at a memory cost (which I want to avoid)

Context:

we are implementing a signal/slot system, in a very constrained environment (memory severely limited). Since we have several millions object which can send or receive signals, this kind of optimization is effective (when it works, of course)

Question:

How can I solve this problem? So far, I have found:

1 - add a virtual method in TBase. Works, but it does not really solve the problem, it avoids it. And it is inefficient (too much memory)

2 - casting to TBase* instead of casting to void* in the array, at the expense of a loss of generality. (probably what I will try next)

Do you see another solution?

Comment: Would simply casting to `TBase*` *before* casting to `void*` solve the problem to your satisfaction? ([See here](https://ideone.com/kpNhe6))

Comment: Just to be clear: Some of your derived classes have virtual methods.  Others do not.  And TBase itself is so small that adding a vtable pointer causes a significant increase in memory size.  Correct?

Comment: Have you considered using templates?

Comment: @DaleWilson Size doesn't matter. If `TBase` had 1000 `int`s in it, this still wouldn't work.

Comment: @gha.st : this will not work in the case of multiple inheritance. See the update in the post.

Comment: A hack (that only works where you explicitly use the address-of operator) is to add to `TBase` the member function `TBase* operator&() { return this; }` (and the `const` version of that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider how the class is laid out in memory. `TBase` is easy, it's just four bytes with one member:

```
 _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|
 ^
 m_iData
```

`TStaticDerived` is the same. However, `TVirtualDerived` is totally different. It now has an alignment of 8 and has to start up front with a vtable, containing an entry for the destructor:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
 ^               ^
 vtable          m_iData
```

So when you cast `vd` to `void*` and then to `TBase*`, you are effectively reinterpreting the first four bytes of your vtable (the offset address into `~TVirtualDerived()`) as `m_iData`. The solution is to first do a `static_cast` to `TBase*`, which will return a pointer to correct starting point of `TBase` in `vd` and *then* to `void*`:

```
vArray[2] = static_cast<TBase*>(&vd); // now, pointer is OK
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated the question to explain why we needed to use this system. static_cast will not work in case of multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Seb I reverted your edit as it's a wall of text that doesn't appreciably change the spirit of the question. Also `static_cast` definitely works with multiple inheritance - the issue is likely that you're casting back and forth to `void*` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in you cast. As you use a C type cast **through void**, it is equivalent to a reinterpret_cast, which can be poor when subclassing. In the first part, type is accessible to compiler and your casts are equivalent to static_cast.

But I cannot understand why you say that you *cannot avoid casting to void* in the first place*. As PrintType internally will convert the `void *` to a `TBase *`, you could as well pass a `TBase **`. In that case it will work fine :

```
void PrintType(TBase** pArray, size_t iSize)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        TBase *pBase = pArray[i];
        pBase->Print();
    }
}
...
    TBase* vArray[3];
    vArray[0] = &b;
    vArray[1] = &sd;
    vArray[2] = &vd; //VTABLE not taken into account -> pointer not OK
    PrintType(vArray, 3);
```

Alternatively, if you **want** to use a `void **` array, you must explicitely make sure that what you put in it are only `TBase *` **and not pointer to subclasses** :

```
void* vArray[3];
vArray[0] = &b;
vArray[1] = static_cast<TBase *>(&sd);
vArray[2] = static_cast<TBase *>(&vd);
PrintType(vArray, 3);
```

Those both method correctly output :

```
Data = 0
Data = 1
Data = 2
Data = 0
Data = 1
Data = 2
```

Comment: The code given was for illustration of the problem (minimal example). In our codebase (>800 000 lines of code), we have a typeless delegate class (see this article for the main idea: [delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible)). Casting to TBase works for most cases, but when multiple inheritance is used, it does not work anymore - we need the original most derived type, or the compiler will not be able to correctly deduce the method address. This is why we cast the object pointer to void - to keep the original pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Forget virtual polymorphism.  Do it the old fashioned way.

Add one byte to each TBase to indicate type and a switch statement in the print method to "Do The Right Thing."  (this saves you sizeof(pointer) -1  bytes per TBase over the virtual method approach.

If adding a byte is still too expensive, consider using C/C++ bit fields (anyone remember those (grin)) to squeeze the type field into some other field that doesn't fill the space available (for example an unsigned integer that has a maximum value of 2^24 - 1)

You code will be ugly, true, but your severe memory constraints are ugly, too. Ugly code that works is better than beautiful code that fails.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We have tried this approach, and it works for most classes. But we have a problem when we want to derive from TBase and another class (from another library) with virtual methods. This is why I post the question.We try to do efficient code, and it is already very ugly ! (but efficient !). The problem with ugly is the maintenance : it is costly (takes more time). And when we need to expand / patch the code 6 month later, we will regret it.